# Python Integration: to calculate area under the curve

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

I want to find the integral of output power `Po` in the following code:

```
Vo = 54.6

# defining a function for duty cycle, output current and output power
def duty_cycle(output_voltage, array_voltage):
    duty_cycle = np.divide(output_voltage, array_voltage)
    return duty_cycle

def output_current(array_current, duty_cycle):
    output_current = np.divide(array_current, duty_cycle)
    return output_current

def output_power(output_voltage, output_current):
    output_power = np.multiply(output_voltage, output_current)
    return output_power

#calculating duty cycle, output current and output power
D = duty_cycle(Vo, array_params['arr_v_mp'])
Io = output_current(array_params['arr_i_mp'], D)
Po = output_power(Vo, Io)

#plot ouput power
plt.ylabel('Output Power [W]')
Po.plot(style='r-')
```

The code above is just a part of a script. `array_params` is a pandas time-series data frame. When plotted pandas Series `Po`, it looks like this:

[image: output power]

This is my first time calculating integral using python. After reading through the internet, I think Python's `scipy` module could be of help but don't really know how and which method to implement. I would appreciate your help in any manner with the above-explained problem.

Comment: Since you have discrete values in an array, don't you just want the sum of that array?

Comment: @Mark I also had the same idea but according to my assignment, I have to plot the integral of ``` Po ``` just similar to how I plotted Po. By sum, I would only get a single value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compute an integral of the form `int y(x) dx` from x0 to x1, with an array `x_array` with values from x0 to x1 and a corresponding `y_array` of same length, one can use numpy's trapezoidal integration:

```py
integral = np.trapz(y_array, x_array)
```

which will work also for non-constant spacing `x_array[i+1]-x_array[i]`.

Answer (score 3):

If an indefinite integral (i.e. an integral `F(t) = integral f(t) dt`) is needed, use `scipy.integrate.cumtrapz` (instead of `numpy.trapz` for definite integrals).

```
integrated = scipy.integrate.cumtrapz(power, dx=timestep)
```

or

```
integrated = scipy.integrate.cumtrapz(power, x=timevalues)
```

To have `integrated` the same length as `power`, specify the initial value of the integral, via the optional parameter `initial` (e.g. `initial=0`) to `scipy.integrate.cumtrapz`.